# Do we need a server for verifying auto-renewable in app purchase subscription?

Tags: iphone, in-app-purchase

I am trying auto-renewable subscription first time.I had implemented old style subscription before. In that case i had a server to verify receipts and adding validity to user. But with this new style "auto-renewvable" subscription , is it really need of a server ? Is there any advantage if we use our own server for verifying receipts ? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

No, you don't *have* to use your own server for this. But the reason it's recommended is that, if you want to verify receipts with iTunes from the app (instead of your server) you'd have to include your `secret` in the app.